# Fatal error when activating WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql

I have already intalled wpgraphql, wpgraphiql and advanced custom fields, but when I try to acctivate WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields the next message appers in wordpress:

```
Warning: require(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql-acf-develop/vendor/composer/../phpstan/phpstan/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql-acf-develop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql-acf-develop/vendor/composer/../phpstan/phpstan/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql-acf-develop/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69
```

Comment: composer run with different user/file rights then web/php server? make files in `vendor` accesible for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the repository for the same issue: https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-acf/issues/222

As suggested you can currently use an older version of the plugin found here: https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-acf/archive/19697681d01b0acafeeac256ca3bd5a68747d73a.zip

Seems to be an issue with the latest version of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try deleting, uploading and trying again

Comment: Having the same issue, deleting and reinstalling is not helping unfortunately